# What is the point of =Record in this definition: interface FieldProps<T extends Record = Record>?

Tags: typescript, generics

I found a generic interface declaration as follows:

```
export interface FieldProps<T extends Record = Record> {
    addLabel?: boolean;
    label?: string;
    record?: T;
    source?: string;
    resource?: string;
    basePath?: string;
    formClassName?: string;
}
```

I can understand **T extends Record**, but what does **= Record** mean?

I've searched but can't find the answer.

Update: Is it a default type?

Comment: I think it is an invalid syntax. Recors has 2 required generic arguments. Even this syntax [T extends Record] is invalid

Comment: I've already figured out it is a default type, like the post mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938617/typescript-force-default-generic-type-to-be-any-instead-of